# Can I decide where iBus:s libpinyin suggestion window is placed?

Tags: input-method, chinese

I'm using iBus for Chinese pinyin input. The little top floating window with suggestions is placed in the lower part of the screen. Can I change it so that it instead always is displayed close to where I'm writing?

---

Version info:

Desktop: XFCE 4

```
$ ibus version
IBus 1.5.11

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.10.0-38-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-059) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017

$ env | grep -E '_IM|XMOD'
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
```

Comment: I tested with `ibus-sunpinyin` on Xubuntu 16.04.3 (Mousepad), and couldn't reproduce the behavior you describe. It works fine on standard Ubuntu as well. So it's hard to advise you. I'm not aware of any setting to control the location of the candidate window.

Comment: Btw, are the input method related variables set correctly, i.e. what does the command `env | grep -E '_IM|XMOD'` output?

Comment: Looks good, even if I'd have expected the `GTK_IM_MODULE` variable to be "ibus" as well. Unfortunately I'm out of ideas.